# Detect behind toy car use opencv in android

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a project to track follow toy car use opencv in java, But i don't know how to detect and create a rectangle for behind car. Below is all of my idea and way that i do , but it still not detect good.

My source image:
[image]

And my goal is detect behind car. Some thing like this (i use Paint to draw :))

[image]

My idea is:

_Convert rgb image to gray image. Use Canny detection to find edge and use GaussianBlur to make image smoother

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(mImageRGBA, thresholded, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY,3);
Imgproc.Canny(thresholded, thresholded, 78, 212);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(thresholded, thresholded, new Size(5, 5), 2.2, 2);
```

My image will look like that

[image]

_ Then, i will use findcontour to find contour of car and draw it.

```
List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
Mat mHierarchy = new Mat();

Imgproc.findContours(thresholded, contours, mHierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) {
      circle_contour = contours.get(i).toArray();
      double contour_length = circle_contour.length;
      if (contour_length < 50) continue;
      Imgproc.drawContours(thresholded,contours,i,new Scalar(255,255,255),2);
      .
      .
      .
```

My image will like that:
[image]

And finally, i will not draw contour and i use minAreaRec to find rectangle which have size suitable. i will this rectangle.

```
//Imgproc.drawContours(thresholded,contours,i,new Scalar(255,255,255),2);// remove this line and continue to find rectangle for car.
     .
     .
     .

Car_Rect = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contours.get(i).toArray()));
float rect_width = Car_Rect.boundingRect().width;
float rect_height = Car_Rect.boundingRect().height;
float rect_ratio = rect_width/rect_height;
Point points[] = new Point[4];
Car_Rect.points(points);
if((Car_Rect.angle<=value1)&&(rect_width>value7)&&(rect_width<value8)&&(rect_height>value9)&&(rect_height<value10))
{
      Imgproc.line(thresholded,points[0],points[1],new Scalar(255, 255, 255),2);
      Imgproc.line(thresholded,points[1],points[2],new Scalar(255,255,255),2);
      Imgproc.line(thresholded,points[2],points[3],new Scalar(255,255,255),2);
      Imgproc.line(thresholded,points[3],points[0],new Scalar(255,255,255),2);

 }
```

value1, value7, value8, value9, value10 is a value of angle, height min, height max, width min, width max which i limit size for rectangle of car. I use trackbar to adjust it.
And result is not good althought i was try to adjust value1,7,8,9,10 is best. And it still have some noise :(

[image]

[image]

[image]

So now, my question that i would like to ask is, is this the right way to detect behind toy car???, if no, whether have other way to do that. Or did i miss something, some step??? How can i dectect exactly behind car to get heigh, width of rectangle the most stable ???

Every answer is appreciated and so many thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar to it.. This will require some effort but quite handful for your requirement. The thing is you can achieve this with haar classifier or cascade classifier. But to detect with it, you need an XML file which contains the data of the image it should recognise . Opencv provides some classifier xml in default like to detect face, eye,mouth, number plates and etc. But unfortunately OpenCv doesn't provide and xml to detect the rear view of a car, so one approach is to create your own classifier xml for your requirement and do a similar coding as you do for object recognition such as face recognition. Don't forget to change the face classifier xml with your custom made xml file.

First read this

http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html

Check this link for step by step process

http://www.tectute.com/2011/06/opencv-haartraining.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, because i need a stable rectangle for object, so are your way is find to detect object and get rectangle with width and height  stable???, and there a one problem is shadow of object, is it fine with object which have a shadow. Whatever, thank you so much for your help

Comment: The shadow effect will be automatically taken care . One thing you have to note that the features are found using haar classifier, but you are the one whose gonna give the dimensions of the rectangle to be drawn around the object . So you manually give the height and width of the rectangle.

Comment: Ok, so many thank to you and maybe i will move to your way, i don't know anything about this method "cascade classifier for Haar features" . It seem to be look like template matching. but i will research it, one again, thank you so much :)